# Superuser color is really really bothersome and fatiguing

Tags: discussion, color

I can't look at that site for too long.  It's not the ewoks or the questions - it is the color scheme.

Please make it possible to browse that site for more than a minute or two

To elaborate - the color scheme is cool, for a logo or some graphic - but IMO it is not a good color scheme to be used for prolonged reading.

How many of the  people who like it actually would set those as their colors for their desktop or browser or favorite IDE?

I know I wouldn't.

Comment: I don't know how you can handle MSO over SU.

Comment: Disable styles :) Go retro...really, really retro.

Comment: @Jonathan: Retro, huh? Could you whip up a Greasemonkey script to make MSO look like an old C64 or Atari game, all nice and pixelated!

Comment: @gnovice I was thinking about writing a script to add some nice '95 gifs and flaming hr's. .gifs FTW!

Comment: i am addicted to that colors, i can surf the site for hours without having any problems

Comment: The blue is really bad!!!

Comment: I've added a feature request asking to have a user preference so that you can choose to override the default color scheme with one from one of the other trilogy sites, if you prefer on over the others. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40337/use-stackoverflow-colors-on-super-user-or-any-other-trilogy-site

Comment: Logically, one of the Trilogy sites must have the most readable scheme (unless you believe that all three schemes are equally readable), in which case all sites should use that most readable scheme.

Answer (score 24):

Really?  I thought SuperUser had the nicest color scheme of the four.

Comment: +1 I also like it best.

Comment: Yeah, SU is my fav, too.

Comment: Yeah it is "nice" but it is hard to look at for too long.  very "noisy"

Comment: well, it is the "funkiest" or "girliest" of the sites.  but that's how its supposed to be.

Comment: Hurts ma glazzballs

Comment: Reminds me of a saying, half of you are monkeys, OK I'll take it back - half of you are not monkeys.

Answer (score 6):

I don't completely agree that the site is hard to read.  I don't have an issue.

However, blue is the hardest color for the human eye to focus on because there are [less blue cones compared to red/green](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/rodcone.html#c3).  This is why blue is often a background color, like in the old school WordPerfect.

Comment: ...and PC-Write!  White text on blue background is the easiest reading.  Not sure why everything is this horrid black text on white background nowadays.  Apple seems to have made it mainstream with the Mac OS and was copied by Windows.  Can we sue Apple for years of eyestrain from that poor design decision?  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The worst offender is the pea-green Accepted Answer background color. The gray arrows and score is really hard to see, the user name has really bad contrast too.

[Here is a link to an accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/2733/is-it-better-to-leave-your-computer-on-all-the-time/2747#2747) so you don't have to hunt around to find one.

EDIT: Looks like the color has been toned down. Nice work!

Comment: apparently not accepted anymore...

Comment: Wow - unaccepting a Jon Skeet answer is unacceptable!

Comment: there are no accepted answer background colors any more

Answer (score 3):

I also do not find the SU color scheme pleasant to the eyes, although I grant you, it's gotten much better.

Comment: yes, it got marginally better.  Still difficult for me to spend any time on it.

Answer (score 3):

Superuser burns my eyes.  After 10 seconds, my eyes hurt.

Comment: Keep staring, the burning will subside

Comment: the burning sensation means it's working!!

Comment: I have to admit....the burning did subside.

Answer (score 2):

I like SU color scheme.

Comment: sure, you can like it, but can you use it as often and as much as the other sites without going blind?

Comment: Yes i can, and in fact im finding myself browsing there much more... I must be one of the 5 people that can stomach it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that color is called "radioactive teal"

But I think part of it is that the tags are outlined instead of solid colored, it makes them kindof indistinct from the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Meh. I like it. The questions are kinda boring so far, but the colors are nice.

Answer (score 1):

don't listen to them!  the site looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Superuser should allow the option to choose the Windows 3.1 "Hot dog vendor" color scheme

Comment: that brings back memories...

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser colors are a-okay EXCEPT

- In comments, it is hard to make out `codified` text because both the comment and codified background colors are white.

Would this be an acceptable and more-user friendly change?